# How to save strings into an array of char pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have to save Strings readen by command line and save them into a pointer array. The problem is that when I save the strings in their respective array [x][y] it seems that after every update on a [x][y] it affects the whole array.
I used some printf to see the state of the array after each udpate and always prints the last value added instead of the previous that should be in the array.
Can someone point me the problem please?

```
char *NFAtab[STATES][SYMBOLS];
void init_NFA_table()
{
    char input[STATES+1];
    int index;
    int state;

    DFA_states = 0;
    N_symbols = 2;

    printf("FUNCIONAMENT:\n No hi ha límit d'estats, però es necessari que els estats comencin per l'estat 0.\n Només s'accepten transicions amb a i b.\n");
    printf("Introdueix nombre d'estats:");
    scanf("%d", &NFA_states);
    printf("--------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Introdueix transicions per cada estat per la 'a' (forma d'introducció: estatestat, sense espaiat; exemple: si va al estat 1 i al 2: 12 | si no hi ha transició '.')\n ------------------------------------------\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NFA_states; i++){
        printf("ESTAT %d: ", i);
        scanf("%s", input);
        if (strcmp(input, ".") == 0){
            NFAtab[i][0] = "";
        } else {
            NFAtab[i][0] = input;
            printf("%s\n", NFAtab[i][0]);
        }

        if (i>0){
            printf("%s\n", NFAtab[i-1][0]);
        }
    }

    printf("Introdueix transicions per cada estat per la 'b' (forma d'introducció: estatestat, sense espaiat; exemple: si va al estat 1 i al 2: 12 | si no hi ha transició '.')\n ------------------------------------------\n");
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < NFA_states; x++){
        printf("ESTAT %d: ", x);
        scanf("%s", input);
        if (strcmp(input, ".") == 0){
            NFAtab[x][1] = "";
        } else {
            NFAtab[x][1] = input;
            printf("%s\n", NFAtab[x][1]);
        }

        if (x > 0){
            printf("%s\n", NFAtab[x-1][1]);
        }
    }

    for (x = 0; x < NFA_states; x++){
        for (i = 0; i < N_symbols; i++){
            printf("ESTAT: %d | SIMBOL: %d : %s\n", x, i, NFAtab[x][i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a 2D array of `char *`.  You may have thought you'd be using a 2D array of `char`.  You need to allocate space to store the strings; you're using the same pointer `input` all the time, but each new input overwrites the previous value.  Look for `strdup()` — not standard C, but standard in POSIX and commonly available elsewhere.  Or use a 2D array of `char` and use `strcpy()` to copy values.

Comment: Depending on how and where `input` is declared, you may have a similar problem with `NFAtab[i][0] = input;`. (you can't assign strings, you must copy them with, e.g. `strcpy`) You can assign the address from a pointer, but if it is a pointer with *automatic* storage, you will be assigning the same address over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first allocate the memory using `malloc` for chat pointer array `NFAtab` then copy the string to memory using `strcpy` function as Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator

Use strcpy for aggisning the string to array

```
if (strcmp(input, ".") == 0){
            strcpy(NFAtab[x][1],");
        } else {
           strcpy( NFAtab[x][1],input);
            printf("%s\n", NFAtab[x][1]);
        }
```

Comment: (and they also do not have automatic storage allocation - note that `NFAtab` is an array of pointers)

Comment: yes need malloc first to get the memory

Comment: Are you going to fix your solution?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

With `NFAtab[i][0] = input;` you assign the address of `input`to the element `NFAtab[i][0]`.

Of course, you do not copy the input, so with every iteration, input is overwritten and the array element pointing to input shows the new value of input.

You should use `malloc` to allocate new memory and copy the input to that memory, then assign that memory to the arrray alement.